# Displaying Mutlidimensional array in php in json format

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, json

I am beginner in API and want to display multidimensional array as json format.
I have three tables in mysql

**category (category_id,category_name,category_description),

**subcategory (subcategory_id,subcategory_name,subcategory_description,category_id,category_name),

**product (product_id,product_name,product_description,product_price category_id, subcategory_id,subcategory_name)**

i want to display the output as

--->category 1

```
 --->subcategory1

        ---->product1

        ---->product2
```

---->category2

```
---->subcategory2

       ----->product1

       ----->product2
```

and so on...

so please help to do the same ..

I am totally choose to display this output in API

For Single category i am using code

```
//*******View Categories From database
    private function viewcategory(){    
            // Cross validation if the request method is GET else it will return "Not Acceptable" status
            if($this->get_request_method() != "GET"){
                $this->response('',406);
            }
            $sql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM category WHERE category_status = 1", $this->db);
            if(mysql_num_rows($sql) > 0){
                $result = array();
                while($rlt = mysql_fetch_array($sql,MYSQL_ASSOC)){
                    $result[] = $rlt;
                }
                // If success everythig is good send header as "OK" and return list of users in JSON format
                $this->response($this->json($result), 200);
            }
            $this->response('',204);    // If no records "No Content" status
        }
    //******End of View Categories Function
```

i want to use the same for all categories

Comment: Start here: http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php

Comment: Just build an array that has the correct format and then json encode it. What have you tried? Where are you stuck? Fetching the data from the database? Iterating the result? Building the array? Encoding it to json?
You need to be much more specific. In it's current state, the question is simply too broad.

Comment: Don't use the deprecated and insecure `mysql_*`-functions. They have been deprecated since PHP 5.5 (in 2013) and were completely removed in PHP 7 (in 2015). Use MySQLi or PDO instead.

Comment: Thank you for your reply .... bt I really don’t know how to create this, means iteration as well as fetching from databases.